# Wires not labeled or color coded

Tags: nest-api

My carpenter disconnected the thermostat while renovating finished space in my detached garage. I had an old Honeywell T87f. The wires (3) are all attached by the plastic insulation that is around them. Of course they're all the same color. No labels on the old thermostat either and it appears that only two of the wires were connected before. How to wire my new Nest?

Comment: This question is off-topic on this board, which is about programming. I am not sure exactly where to point you, though - perhaps others are.

Comment: Please point me in right direction.

Comment: You should contact Nest support (support.nest.com), as noted this is a site for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact nest trained installers

https://nest.com/support/#pro